# Group by --> Not all results are shown

Tags: group-by

the following simple sql query does not show all results (one is missing):

```
SELECT SUM(stunden.stunden) as stunden, user.name, projekte.hmax as hmax 
FROM stunden 
LEFT JOIN user on stunden.user_id = user.ID
LEFT JOIN projekte ON stunden.projekt_id=projekte.ID
WHERE stunden.projekt_id=1031 GROUP BY user.ID
```

This one shows all:

```
SELECT stunden, user.name, projekte.hmax as hmax 
FROM stunden 
LEFT JOIN user on stunden.user_id = user.ID
LEFT JOIN projekte ON stunden.projekt_id=projekte.ID
WHERE stunden.projekt_id=1031
```

I can't figure out, whats wrong...!

Can u help me please ;-(
Best regards

Daniel

Edit:

The first query puts out all datasets correctly:

```
stunden   username    hmax 
------------------------------ 
5         testuser_1  12
3         testuser_1  12
1         testuser_2  12
1         testuser_2  12
```

But i want an output like this:

```
stunden   username    hmax 
------------------------------ 
8         testuser_1  12
2         testuser_2  12
```

Why does the second query not work but the first does?

Comment: Please add your SQL engine in the tags (e.g. `mysql).`

Comment: @A.L I'm guessing it's MySQL looking at the non aggregate columns in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Update your question with sample data and your desired output.

Comment: Sorry, problem solved. with left join now all results are shown...

Comment: You can add an answer with your solution.